# Body could not be parsed as valid XML/AMF/JSON in Flash builder AMF and MySql

Tags: mysql, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, amfphp

I have search the net and am un able to resolve this issue
Due to my weak programming skills I do panic and wonder perhaps im just doing it wrong obviously lol
Just wondered if anyone could give me some insight to work out my issue!
i have a Flash Builder 4.5 web site connecting with AMF to MySql database
I can query the database as well as delete, update, search and i have even got pagination working!
But when it comes to inserting a row of data I get the above error message
Now every thing works even when I test the php script in flash builder **Test Operation** 
So I just need someone to tell me can I send an ValueObject to Mysql or do i need to convert it into something else?
As im sending it as the object but its only inserting the first 2 values and the other 8 are missing and i get the above error in **Network Monitor**

On searching this issue most people that ask this question and don't get an answer.
The error is displayed in the response of **Network Monitor** so is the a php error or mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I have solved the problem. as in I still get the error but I think I know why but it all works now so I'm happy with that :)

and the reason I was getting the error was for some reason I didn't think that it mattered with variable name consistence through the different programming types, I just assumed that the compiler worked it all out by magic lol.

So in flex I had Country and in "Flash builder Test Operation" I had Country and on my mysql database I had CountryCode. The reason I think I still get the error is because there are still cells within the newly created row that are left NULL as these will be updated later :) hope my silly mistake that cost me many days will helps some one :)